# iOS Swift WKWebKit with MBCircularProgressBarView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

before posting this I was looking on the internet how to implement from cocoa pods **MBCircularProgressBarView** in iOS Swift WKWebKit to track progress of loading website.
I have tried with combination of some other progress bar codes but it didn't work.

I have tried to implement `self.progressView.value = 0` in `viewDidLoad` 
and

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0){
            self.progressView.value = 100
        }
```

in

```
didFinish navigation
```

which shows circular bar and animate but doesn't show proper loading progress.

Any idea how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class `class WebpageViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate` containing:

```
@IBOutlet weak var activitySpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var activityLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    activitySpinner.tintColor = R.color.YumaRed
    activitySpinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityLabel.text = "Loading..."
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://...")!))
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
{
    activitySpinner.startAnimating()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
{
    activitySpinner.stopAnimating()
    activityLabel.isHidden = true
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
{
    activitySpinner.stopAnimating()
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
}
```